# Copy constructor for a binary search tree is being called infinitely

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am writing a constructor for a binary search tree, the problem is that the helper function within the tree is being called infinitely, this eventually generates a stack overflow.

```
void copyTree(myTreeNode* & copy, const myTreeNode* & originalTree)
{
    if(originalTree==NULL)
    {
        copy=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        copy=new myTreeNode();
        cout<<"This is the data my friend: "<<endl<<copy->data.getCharacter()<<endl;
        copy->data=originalTree->data;
        copyTree(copy->left, originalTree->getLeft());
        copyTree(copy->right,originalTree->getRight());
    }
}

//this is the copy constructor for the tree
myTree (const myTree & copy)
{
    this->copyTree(this->root,copy.getRoot());
}

//and this is the way I have written the getLeft and getRight Functions
//they both return references to the left and rightNodes

const myTreeNode *& getLeft() const
{
    const myTreeNode*  ptr=NULL;
    if(this->left)
    {
        ptr=this->left;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

P.S the data object is not a primitive data type but it has no dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Is `myTreeNode::left` always initialized to `NULL`? If not, you might never reach a base case because `getLeft()` never returns `NULL`. I'd think a junk value would cause a segmentation fault, though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how this might be causing infinite recursion, but your `getLeft()` function seems suspect.  You're returning a reference to something on the stack.  Who knows what's happening to that memory after that.  It looks like you keep on using that same slot in memory over and over again, so you might be creating a loop instead of a tree.

Change it so that it returns a pointer, not a reference to a pointer (remove the '&').

Comment: good call -- I think your sense of the memory behavior agrees with what I would expect any C compiler to do under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

@JCooper figured it out -- I'm just providing sample code. The getLeft() function should look more like this. Please note that I am NOT creating any NEW variables, so there is no stack lifespan problem.

```
const myTreeNode * getLeft() const
{
    //may be NULL
    return this->left;
}
```

(EDIT: made code more concise. Thanks @molbdnilo!)

Comment: You can express that more concisely: if `this->left` is non-null, you're returning `this->left`; if it's null, you're returning the null pointer, which is the value of `this->left`. So you can replace the entire body of `getLeft` with `return this->left`.

Comment: My intent was originally that it should be verbose on purpose, to make the two cases clear. Now, I think you're right that this is sufficiently wasteful that a comment is probably a better choice for clarity!